# Prove that for all $x$, $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ there exist $z$, $g$ such that $x = z + g$, $y = z - g$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

if I want to prove the following:

$\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}\,\,\,\exists\,\,z, g : x = z + g, y = z - g$

Can the resolution of the following system act as a proof:

$\begin{cases} x = z + g\\ 
y = z - g\end{cases}$
$\implies$
$\begin{cases} z = x - g\\ 
y = (x - g) - g\end{cases}$
$\implies$
$\begin{cases} z = x - g\\ 
g = \frac{x - y}{2}\end{cases}$
$\implies$
$\begin{cases} z = \frac{x + y}{2}\\
g = \frac{x - y}{2}\end{cases}$

If so, why? Or is there more?

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the verification that $x=z+g$, $y=z-g$, or at least a sentence like "we see this indeed holds". Other than that it is fine. In fact, you don't need to show the system, if you show the verfication.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something more like:

$\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}\,\,\,\exists\,\,z, g : x = z + g, y = z - g$

**Proof**

Let Z=$\frac{x+y}{2}$ and G=$\frac{x-y}{2} $

$$\frac{x+y}{2} + g$$
$$=\frac{x+y+2g}{2}$$
$$=\frac{x+y+2(\frac{x-y}{2})}{2}$$
$$=\frac{2x+y-y}{2}$$
$$=x$$

I would repeat this for $y$ and then explicitly state my conclusion.